# Next js Выдает ошибки при запуске

Tags: javascript, next.js

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\tvc\Desktop\Мои работы\13.06.22\App-Next/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tvc\Desktop\Мои работы\13.06.22\App-Next\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: Там же написано что `no such file or directory` и указывает на конкретный файл.

Comment: он существует все скачено но запускаться не хочет

Comment: попробуйте расположить проект чтобы в полном пути не было пробелов таких как в `Мои работы`, после `A complete log of this run can be found in` должен быть указан файл лога, загляните в него для подробностей

Answer (score 0):

1. На всякий случай проверьте/обновите версию `npm`: `npm install -g npm@latest`
2. очистить `npm` кэш:  `npm cache clean --force`
3. удалить папку `node_modules` и `package-lock.json` (можно еще `.next`)
4. запустить заново: `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

next js создаёт дополнительную папку при запуске, и нужно в неё перейти

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]